# Google storage count number of objects in a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm looking for a fast way to get the number of archive in a bucket now i'm doing somthing like this

```
gsutil ls -r gs://my_bucket/ | grep tar.gz | wc -l
```

But it's incredibly slow.

Comment: Not sure if it's faster but maybe you can try using the storage API? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/

Comment: Don't see a count endpoint for bucket service :(

Answer (score 1):

The fastway way would be using either Google Cloud Monitoring [1] and watching the `Count of objects` metric or enabling bucket logging [2] and looking in storage logs.

These two methods are particularly useful when your bucket contains very large number of objects and listing them with API takes too long.

Please note however that both [1] and [2] doesn't show up-to-the-minute information and often refreshed only once in 24 hours. Still, sometimes, this is the only way.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/available-metrics

[2]https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

Comment: Thanks. Because I'm doing some process on the file in the bucket and after the process I should remove the file. I need fresh count (max 10 min old).

Comment: ~ 100 000 file / day. Google storage will be use for ephemeral storage

Comment: You can try to perform ```gsutil ls``` from an instance on Google Compute Engine. If you're already doing that, I am afraid this is the best you can get, given you need the count data refreshed recently.

Comment: Whatever thanks for the response. Really weird because when i try to delete the bucket, a warning message display the number of objects :(

Comment: Is it an up to date number of objects? I would suspect they are fetching it from bucket metadata which is updated periodically but nowhere near 10 min you need.